# Yii2 vs Laravel

Tags: php, yii2, laravel

В yii есть такая реализация приложения как:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';

$config = require_once(__DIR__ . '/../config/console.php');
$application = new yii\console\Application($config);
```

После этого в любом файле будут доступны все компоненты фреймворка. Есть ли аналогичный код Laravel ?

Comment: И зачем это вообще?..

Comment: @VladimirGonchar
У меня сокет крутится отдельно от приложения, мне нужно как-то работать с пользователями. Писать свой велосипед не хочется. Я хочу использовать Eloquent от Laravel. Или же существует другой способ ?

Comment: если вы хотите использовать Eloquent, то надо и ставить Eloquent. И, соответственно, **спрашивать, как поставить Eloquent**. Это же очень просто: описывать именно ту проблему, которую вам надо решить. А не очередную яму на той кривой дорожке, которую вы выбрали для решения своей проблемы.

Comment: @Ипатьев
Вот именно, что пока что мне нужно только Eloquent, но не много времени у нужны будут Laravel-овские фасады. Поэтому и спрашиваю за экземпляр всего приложения.

Comment: Может прозвучит банально... используй ларавель:)